# Keep ViewState data after redirect\Server.Transfer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, postback, viewstate

I have some HiddenField That i put some string in. After the user click on save button, Before the page refreshing I save the data from the HiddenField  in ViewState, because the page lose the data in HiddenField.
i'm using Server.Transfer for the refresh.

However the ViewState is null after all.

Any suggestion?
Thank

Server.Transfer("mypage.aspx?id=" + p_orderid);

Comment: More info is required for a good answer but i think you will lose viewstate if you transfer because viewstate is for a single page. maybe use sessionstate?

Comment: Use Session if you are allowed to use it. Session[p_orderid]= p_orderid; Server.Transfer("mypage.aspx"); In mypage.aspx, you can retrieve Session[p_orderid]